# "Invalid License File" while using CMake with Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, avr-studio6

After installing AVR Studio, CMake returns an error saying "Invalid License Key" while trying to generate a new project using the MSVC generator.  This may also happen if other tools based on Visual Studio 2010 are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by AVR Studio (and possibly) other products installing a "devenv.exe" in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.  By default, CMake will attempt to use "devenv.exe" and fall back on "MSBuild" if it is not found.  MSVC Express 2010 does not use a "devenv.exe", but instead has its own executable.  To fix this problem, rename the "devenv.exe" file to "devenv1.exe" while generating an MSVC 10 file using CMake.  It may be necessary to rename it back to get the other tools to work but so far it has not been a problem.